# Find the k missing Bitstrings in the Array

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, fetch, bit

I have the Problem given:

"n,k,l are positive integers. You have an array A with n=2^l-k elements. The elements of the array are pairwise different binary strings. So k binary strings are missing in the array.
The only way you can access A is by calling the function FetchBit(i, j), which returns the jth bit of the string A[i].

Suppose n= 2^l-k, i.e. exactly k of the bit strings do not appear in A. Describe an algorithm to find the k missing bit strings in A using only O(nlog(k)) calls to FetchBit."

I could solve a it with k=1 in O(n) by counting the times 1 and 0 are in the first position and then continue with the strings who start with the the less occurring number.(so n +n/2 +n/4+... steps)
But for k I could not get my head around this Problem.

Comment: Hint: Given some i, choose i bit positions somehow. With n\*i queries you can count the frequencies of bit strings having each of the 2^i possible patterns of states at these bit positions. If these frequencies turn out to be all the same, we haven't learned anything. Is it possible to choose i to force them *not* to turn out all the same?

Comment: @j_random_hacker i= log(n) is the first position where we need to learn something because they are then more possible patterns then we have bitstrings in the array. But if we call n*log(n) times FetchBit we are already bigger then n*log(k) in a lot of cases.
Maybe i did not understood you correctly, but this is what i deduced out of your hint.

Comment: You can learn something before then. Slightly cryptic hint: 2^l - 2^i is not divisible by 2^(i+1) for any i < l. (I'm thinking about the case where k is a power of 2 BTW, which I think is a "worst case".)